Can the collective hive identify what sets these bags are from?
We got a job lot of LEGO, mostly without instruction manuals, but I’ve been able to identify what sets they were from with the exception of these two batches of bags. I think the bigger bags (picture 1) are from 10313 Wildflower Bouquet but just can’t get what set the smaller bags (picture 2) are from.
1:

2:

All thoughts gratefully welcomed !

This question is similar to: How can I identify a set based on one or more original sealed bags?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Bag 3 of your second picture has a lot of pirate hat (bicorne) in dark purple, which means they're also part of Wildflower Bouquet.
Yes, there can be several bags with the same number.
